# Dynamically add printthis button to a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, printthis

Sorry if I'm missing something (i'm a beginner in JS). I am looking to use the [PrintThis.js](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis) JQuery plugin to add a print button to any div with the "printdiv" class. I am using Jquery to number off the buttons and div classes and append the needed JQuery code to the script tag at the bottom of the page.

Here is a codepen I made with the code I am using. https://codepen.io/hinte019/pen/yEybmG?editors=1010

Here is it also in code form

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="printthis/printThis.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="printdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptatibus, magni, alias eaque dolor quisquam placeat, similique atque ratione fugiat impedit nam numquam accusantium. Deserunt reiciendis nulla omnis necessitatibus, quo.</p></div>
        <div class="printdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit labore commodi, magnam corrupti dignissimos hic soluta. Distinctio quod saepe, tempora inventore ipsum, eligendi, dignissimos, eos recusandae perspiciatis odit consequuntur! Optio.</p></div>
        <div class="printdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate distinctio fugiat earum, quibusdam soluta ipsa voluptas porro nostrum cupiditate vel modi nesciunt sint rem, vitae id exercitationem debitis, saepe eius?</p></div>
        <script>
        $(function () {
            // print divs
            var i = 1;
            $("body script").append('$(document).ready(function () {');
            $('.printdiv').each(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('printdiv').addClass('printdiv'+i);
                $('.printdiv'+i).prepend('<button type=\"button'+i + '\" class=\"btn btn-primary printbutton' +i + '\">Print<\/button>');
                var printcode = '\r\n        $(\'.printbutton'+i + '\').click(function () {\r\n            $(\'.printdiv'+i + '\').printThis();\r\n        });';
                $("body script").append(printcode);
                i++;
            });
            $("body script").append('\r\n});');
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This results in printing

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.printbutton1').click(function () {
        $('.printdiv1').printThis();
    });
    $('.printbutton2').click(function () {
        $('.printdiv2').printThis();
    });
    $('.printbutton3').click(function () {
        $('.printdiv3').printThis();
    });
});
```

The resulting code should be right, but the print buttons do not work :(

Comment: Make sure that the file printThis.js is in the correct folder that you refer to it

Comment: It is showing up in sources in Chrome DevTools so that should be good

Comment: Question: Why don't the print buttons appear in the source code rather than appending them? If it's just to print that specific element, there are easier ways to do this and only pass that selector to printThis.

Comment: The content contributor wants to be able to select the text copy in the wysiwyg and add a print button to it. The wysiwyg supports adding a "style" (classes) to the selected content (in tinyMCE).

Comment: See my answer below - you can just append a `<button>` - no need to index, etc. and then use jquery to find the parent container and pass that to printThis. This approach would greatly simplify your codebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `script` in the body, in which you append your code, has already been parsed/processed by the js engine so you cannot alter its contents.

You should create an in-memory `script` and after you fill it then append it to the DOM.

```
$(function() {
  // print divs
  var i = 1;
  var script = $('<script>');
  script.append("$(document).ready(function () {");
  $(".printdiv").each(function() {
    $(this)
      .removeClass("printdiv")
      .addClass("printdiv" + i);
    $(".printdiv" + i).prepend(
      '<button type="button' +
        i +
        '" class="btn btn-primary printbutton' +
        i +
        '">Print</button>'
    );
    var printcode =
      "\r\n        $('.printbutton" +
      i +
      "').on('click', function () {\r\n            $('.printdiv" +
      i +
      "').printThis();\r\n        });";
    script.append(printcode);
    i++;
  });
  script.append("\r\n});");
  script.appendTo('body');
});
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Great explanation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to accomplish what you want:

Change to html (including print button in the source code):

```
<div class="printdiv">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary printbutton">Print</button>
</div>
<div class="printdiv">
    <p>consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary printbutton">Print</button>
</div>
<div class="printdiv">
    <p>vitae id exercitationem debitis</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary printbutton">Print</button>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.printButton').on('click', function(){
    var $parent = $(this).parent('.printdiv');
    $parent.printThis();
});
```

This jQuery says on click of a `button`, find that `button`'s parent `div` matching the class `printDiv` and passes that as the selector for `printThis`.

Additionally, I would suggest moving all javascript/jQuery out of the page an into it's own file.

So you would have:

```
<script src="path/to/jQuery"></script>
<script src="path/to/printThis"></script>
<script src="path/to/your/custom/javascript"></script>
```

Important note:

- Appending `<script>` dynamically is typically not necessary, and is a very roundabout klunky way of affecting the DOM.
- Use `$.on('click',...` instead of `$.click`. For `$.click` a separate handler gets created for every single element that matches the selector and only works for elements already in the DOM (hence your problem in your initial code). `$.on` works for dynamically added elements